# How to Play a Video in a Vuforia Image Target in Unity in 2022?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

How can I have a video play in a Vuforia Image target using Unity? The Vuforia core samples seem overly complicated.

I saw that they put a scrip in the previous answer but it doesn't work. Unfortunately times have changed and for example the OnTrakindFound and OnTrakindLost  functions are not recognized by unity version 2021.3.10f1.I don't know if someone can help me with an updated script that works for me to link a video player to an image target and play it recently when the camera ar de vuforia me detect the image and I stay more or less like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izJatV5ypvM

Comment: just create a render texture with a video and make it a child of the image target.
if you want to play when you find the target, you can use a public method that start the video and stop and connect it to the unity event of find and lost target.

Comment: As a friend? The truth is I am new with this unity and vuforia and just I could put an audio with help. I'm more of Aumentaty

Comment: Your script does not compile. I get mistake after mistake. You know why it can be. It throws me these three mistakes. The script does not work. Attached images:first error: Assets\Test.cs(6,14): error CS0101: The namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'Test' 2°error Assets\Test.cs(9,18): error CS0111: Type 'Test' already defines a member called 'Start' with the same parameter types 3° error Assets\Test.cs(13,17): error CS0111: Type 'Test' already defines a member called 'FindVideoPlayer' with the same parameter types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.create a plane game object.

2.then add the component VideoPlayer to the plane.

3.drag your video to video clip.

4.create an image target.(for details how to do that check on vuforia website).
https://library.vuforia.com/objects/create-and-load-targets-unity

5.make the plane child of the image target.

and now try it, if you want to play when find you can do it by script on the plane like that:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
    private void Start()
    {
        videoPlayer = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
    }
    public void FindVideoPlayer(bool isFind)
    {
        if(isFind)
        {
            videoPlayer.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            videoPlayer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

and on the image target you have onFind and OnLost event, add the plane game object there and choose the FindVideoPlayer and set the bool true when found and false when lost.
If it helped, please mark that I solved it, if not, I'd love to see the details so I can help

Comment: Your script does not compile. I get mistake after mistake. You know why it can be. It throws me these three mistakes. The script does not work. Attached images:

Comment: Your script does not compile @NoamRiahi. I get mistake after mistake. You know why it can be. It throws me these three mistakes. The script does not work. Attached images:

Comment: first error: Assets\Test.cs(6,14): error CS0101: The namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'Test'           2°error Assets\Test.cs(9,18): error CS0111: Type 'Test' already defines a member called 'Start' with the same parameter types                            
 3° error Assets\Test.cs(13,17): error CS0111: Type 'Test' already defines a member called 'FindVideoPlayer' with the same parameter types @PeterSmith

Comment: first error: Assets\Test.cs(6,14): error CS0101: The namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'Test'.                                               
second error: Assets\Test.cs(9,18): error CS0111: Type 'Test' already defines a member called 'Start' with the same parameter types. 3° error: Assets\Test.cs(13,17): error CS0111: Type 'Test' already defines a member called 'FindVideoPlayer' with the same parameter types

Answer (score 0):

@Netomaster23 The message indicates this class "Test" is already contained within your assets somewhere.

Check the list of scripts within your assets for a duplicate class definition.