Step process for creating a working video player for AR Vuforia/Unity
Hello i have been struggling to get my AR video player to work would it be possible for someone to give me some guidance on the steps needed to take and if possible a script please. This is a Vuforia/unity project and i have already got Vuforia set up with a target image.
Any help would be much appreciated. I have tried with adding video player to plane then building project but video does not play.
Thank you
Ryan

Hi, I answered this in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78049943/how-to-integrate-video-to-image-target-in-unity-2022-version/78081850#78081850 see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73965772/how-to-play-a-video-in-a-vuforia-image-target-in-unity-in-2022?rq=2, though the script seems to be faulty.

Thank you, I will give the steps a go and see if it works.

Hello i have followed all steps and everything seems to be ok no errors in  console. However my video does not display there is just a blank black screen with the audio from the video playing. Would you have any ideas why that would be?

I have now managed to get the videoplayer working and displaying the video correctly. What i did was open another project with the Vuforia core samples installed. I then copied all the game objects and cross referenced game objects and the inspector components in both projects and it seemed like that worked for me.
